# How can I disable drop events in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

we are trying to implement CKEditor 5 into our apps and we are struggling a bit with docs.

We want to disable drop event into an editing area or control it somehow. Is there an event for that?

We were trying `editor.model.document.on('clipboardInput')` or `editor.model.document.on('dragover')` without any luck. These events are not fired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to listen to the [`dragover`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html#event-event:dragover) and [`drop`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_document-Document.html#event-event:drop) events on the [view layer](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#view) instead of on [the model](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#model).

I prepared a simple function that can be loaded as a plugin to CKEditor 5 which cancels these events:

```
/**
 * Cancel the `drop` and `dragover` events.
 *
 * @param {module:core/editor/editor~Editor} editor
 */
function cancelDropEvents( editor ) {
    // High priority means that the callbacks below will be called before other CKEditor's plugins.

    editor.editing.view.document.on( 'drop', ( evt, data ) => {
        // Stop executing next callbacks.
        evt.stop();

        // Prevent the default event action.
        data.preventDefault();
    }, { priority: 'high' } );

    editor.editing.view.document.on( 'dragover', ( evt, data ) => {
        evt.stop();
        data.preventDefault();
    }, { priority: 'high' } );
}
```

You can check how it works online – https://jsfiddle.net/pomek/qz0o9ku0/.